# Setting selected option in a partial view using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

The dropdown in my partial looks like this:

```
<select id="odStatus" class="odStatus">
  <option value="placed">Placed</option>
  <option value="shipped">Shipped</option>
  <option value"Completed">Completed</option>
  <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option> 
</selection>
```

In my orders.hbs, I retrieve data which includes an status string

```
$.get("/getOrderDetail/"+ id, (data)=>{
  // ...
  $('#orderDetail').find('#odStatus value=[' + data.order.status + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
  // ...
}
```

I'm trying to get it so `#odStatus` shows what the status is, but I can't get to to work.

Comment: Btw, you should use .prop to set and unset properties, not .attr; like `.prop('selected',true)`

Answer (score 0):

The immediate issue is because your selector assumes `value` is its own element, eg. `<value>`. Instead this should be an attribute selector targeting the `option` elements within the `select` and using `prop()` to update it, like this:

```
$('#orderDetail').find('#odStatus option[value="' + data.order.status + '"]').prop('selected', true);
```

*However*, it's worth noting that the logic can be simplified by just setting the `val()` on the `select` directly. Similarly the `find()` can be removed as it's redundant; `id` attributes have to be unique within the DOM. Try this:

```
$('#odStatus').val(data.order.status);
```

Comment: Setting the val of the Select is not exactly the same, though. Setting the selected property on the option for example gives it the ability to 'reset' to the correct value via form functions.

Comment: What do you think `$("select").val(value)` does?  It sets the `selected` property on the matching option - there's no "value=" property on a `select` - so yes, it is *exactly* the same thing (unless you can provide proof otherwise)

Comment: It does not set the selected property, that would be foolish since it would destroy your original value that you need for a reset whenever you manipulate the value of the Select element. And just cause the html does not give it a value attribute does not mean that the element does not have a javascript property value. Just try it.

Comment: I'm not going to try it. You made the claim. It's on you to show evidence

Comment: Lol, you made the claim in your answer that it is the same. Anyhow, you can play around and see here: https://jsfiddle.net/nc4xsmvq/

Comment: There may be some crossed wires here then as your fiddle works. The value is reset as I would expect it to be.

Comment: But as you see, the selected property is not touched by the Javascript, and the Reset button reverts to the original selected option, not the one set by .val(). That is the point.

Comment: Ah I see your point now. The issue is that manually changing the `selected` attribute to change the `option` shown is normally a mistake by beginners - for the reason you've shown; it doesn't allow the form to be reset back to the state it was in when it was loaded. It's *very* rare for anyone to want, or even need, to do that. At the very least it's bad UX. This is why using `val()` is the better practice.

Comment: Yes, I was just noting that it is not 'exactly' the same XD

Comment: True, although I didn't say it was in the answer.

Comment: I was not trying to imply you did, just thought it would be a useful differentiation for people reading the answer.